# using CDK with existing Stack Templates

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, templates, stack, aws-cdk

I have been trying to move towards using CDK along with our current 10 existing stack templates. This would be great since I can load the template using cfninclude and then add any new resources or modify existing resources in the template using code instead of manually doing it in all the templates.
I got a requirement today to add an Application Load Balancer Listener rule to all templates, so when I reached out to aws support on how to access the load balancer in the templates and add the rule programmatically I was told:

---

*Now, to add a listener rule to the listener defined in the template, we will have to create a new
CfnListenerRule resource,*

```
new elbv2.CfnListenerRule(this, "ListenerRule", {
  listenerArn: listner.attrListenerArn,
  priority: 123,
  conditions: [
    { field: "path-pattern", values: ['/'] }
  ],
  actions: [ { type: "forward", targetGroupArn: <target group ARN> , } ]
});
```

*I tried to replicate the same at my end by setting targetGroupArn: tg.attrTargetGroupArn , but unfortunately I could see the error “Property 'attrTargetGroupArn' does not exist on type 'CfnTargetGroup'.”*

*Therefore, I would suggest you to go with either of these options,*

- *create the stack first and then hardcode the ARN of the target group.*
- *Create the listener rule as a resource in the template and then use cfn-include.*

---

These proposed options seem absurd to me, I don't want to hardcode ARN's in my code for every deployed stack and I don't want to keep manually updating 10 different templates whenever I need to make a change, this defeats the purpose of  CDK doing the work for me.

I'm seriously questioning the value of using a CDK once there are existing stack templates deployed and in production. Has anyone successfully done this without just creating more over head?

Comment: We are moving away from this hybrid approach and just migrating all stacks to CDK code manually and dumping the templates all together. Less headache.

Answer (score 1):

We have decided to just migrate the templates to code, but for anyone who needs to know how to do this, here you go from AWS support:

```
const template = new cfninc.CfnInclude(this, 'Template', { 
  templateFile: '/Users/abhithm/Downloads/importks.yaml',
});

const lb = template.getResource('LoadBalancer');

const listner = template.getResource('Listener') as elbv2.CfnListener;

const tg = template.getResource('TargetGroup1') as elbv2.CfnTargetGroup;;

const x = tg.ref;

new elbv2.CfnListenerRule(this, "ListenerRule", {
  // listenerArn: listner.getAtt('Arn').toString(),
  listenerArn: listner.attrListenerArn,
  priority: 123,
  conditions: [
    { field: "path-pattern", values: ['/'] }
  ],
  actions: [ { type: "forward", targetGroupArn: x  , } ]
});
```